# PDO Count & Loop Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Information**

I am starting to notice a trend in my coding habits that I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

**Problem**

For the sake of an example, lets pretend I have a table that may have data in it, ideally I want to loop through the data if there is any, if not display an error message.

**Current Solution**

```
function countResults($type){

    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE type = :type');
    $STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));
    return $STH->fetchColumn();

}

if($class->countResults("1") != 0){

    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = :type ');
    $STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));

    while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo "Row Name:".$row['name']."<br />";

    }

}    else    {

     echo "None found";

}
```

**Attempts Made**

I have tried a solution of cutting this down by storing `$STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` into a variable then using `if(!empty($var)){// loop code};` but it doesn't allow me to loop out the data correctly.

**Conclusion**

I understand this isn't a ground breaking bug that I am struggling to fix urgently, but I feel as if this is becoming a bad habit and there's a little nag in my mind that there is a smarter solution to this which I would love to learn before it turns into a habit!

Feel free to ask questions if needed, Thank you.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com BTW, you should not use `SELECT *`, but use specific field names. And you should use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting content to HTML markup.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Thanks Marcel, But the above code is an example describing the situation I am asking a question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is rather illogical than wrong. All you need is common sense.
Imagine you're going to buy a six-pack. Are you getting cash from the pocket in two actions, or one? Are you really do like this:

1. Reach into pocket, only to feel the money. There are some. Okay.
2. *Take the hand back* and then reach again - for the money this time.

Why not to reach just once, and buy your beer if you get enough, or say sorry if not?

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = :type ');
$STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));
$data = $STH->fetchAll();

if ($data)
{
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        echo "Row Name:".$row['name']."<br />";
    }

} else {

     echo "None found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does using two different fetch methods query the database twice?

Comment: Sorry, missed this one. Fixed now.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your revised version.

Comment: You also may want to assign fetched data to the *template* variable instead of echoing it deirectly

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I would use. Option one, similar to what you are doing:

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = :type ');
$STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));
if ($STH->rowCount() > 0)  
  while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "Row Name:".$row['name']."<br />";
  }
}    else    {
  echo "None found";
}
```

Note that the PHP manual for [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.rowcount.php) warns that this might not return the number of rows from a SELECT query on all database types.

What I actually do, is separating the SQL logic from the display, usually by using the template engine [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). In that case you have two separate files:

PHP:

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = :type ');
$STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));
$objects = $STH->fetchAll();
$template->assign("objects", $objects); // this assigns the array with all returned rows to the template.
```

Smarty Template:

```
{foreach from=$objects item=object}
Row Name: {$object.name}<br />
{foreachelse}
None found
{/foreach}
```

This will basically output the same, with separated logic.

Both methods will prevent doing unnessecary queries or doing the same query twice.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, This question has been answered but I will defiantly look into using Smarty in future projects (Too far down the rabbit hole with the current one!) Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, if anyone sees anything wrong please point it out:

- I prefer foreach because I can access the field name
- I like to get used to use count() instead of rowCount() because rowCount() can return 2 for an updated row, even if this query is a select, I feel like I could get used to it and have mistakes.
- I like to check if it returns false to debug. Normally I do a one-liner for this, so I can comment it out or remove it easily on production

---

```
function myQuery(){
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = :type ');
    $STH->execute(array(':type' => $type));
    $data = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($data === false) return "SQL query Error"; // or a method/function that returns the actual error code/message";
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $k => $v) echo "$k: $v<br>"; // I actually prefer to return the array $data and handle the info elsewhere
    } else {
        "None Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: function that deals with database should never ever echo anything. But return data only. Returning the error message is also a bad idea. count() is useless as well. `if($data)` is anough

Comment: I return the error only when debugging, also, the echo was just to follow the given example, If you read the comments it says that actually I normally return the value ;D But you are right on the count, I was going to display the total, then decided not to, deleted the variable holding the count and messed up xD

Comment: Nah it was just a mess up, the count was initially to display "x Results Found", and changing the code up and down the count finished there